# Showing that distinct members of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, compactness

**Definition:**

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are two covers of $X.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of  $\mathcal{B}$ is contained in some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ We say that $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A}$ if each member of $\mathcal{B}$ is a proper subset of some member of $\mathcal{A}.$ if $\mathcal{B}$ strictly refines $\mathcal{A},$ we write $\mathcal{A} < \mathcal{B}.$

Here is the problem:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, and let $\epsilon > 0.$

(a) Show that $X$ has a finite cover $\mathcal{A}$ clopen sets with diameter at most $\epsilon.$

( I am working on writing its details now.)

(b) Show that there is a clopen cover $\mathcal{B}$  such that $\mathcal{B}$ refines $\mathcal{A}$ and distinct numbers of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint.

**My questions are:**

1-I received a hint for the first part of (b) to consider the minimal (with respect to inclusion ) nonempty intersections of members of $\mathcal{A},$ which I am unable to implement its details, Could anyone help me in proving this , please?

2-For the second part of $(b)$ which is showing that distinct numbers of $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint, I am stuck on this. could anyone help me in proving this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do b):

Just let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots A_n\}$.

Define $B_i = A_i \setminus \bigcup_{j < i} A_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

These form a clopen partition that refines $\mathcal{A}$. This idea works for countable covers too.
It's a partition, because if $x \in X$, we can define $i(x)=\min \{i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: x \in A_i\}$. Then $x \in B_{i(x)}$ and $x \in B_i$ iff $i=i(x)$.

Comment: Is this an answer for my second question only?

Comment: No I am not speaking about $(a),$ I am speaking about my question $1-$

Comment: No I mean my first question 1 not question $a$

Comment: @Happy you have to take the minimal intersections *including the complements of members of $\mathcal{A}$* that refine $\mathcal{A}$. That will make them disjoint.

Comment: my questions 1,2 both about part $(b)$ of the main question

Comment: @Happy this way your questions on (b) are moot now, agreed?

Comment: Okay,  agreed :))

Comment: Could you please add more details about my question #1 in your answer?

Comment: @Happy I'm happy with my proof, the other one is too involved. You could invoke theory: take the atoms in the generated Boolean sub-algebra by $\mathcal{A}$. These are disjoint and form a refinement. If you know that theory already it's shorter,  otherwise don't bother.

Comment: Okay thank you! your proofs are always simple :)

Comment: Is it assumed that $A_1$ includes $A_2$ and  $A_2$ includes $A_3$ .... and so on?

Comment: @Happy No, that's not needed.

Comment: Is not the construction of $\mathcal {B}$ needed to be disjoint.... this is why you are constructing it like this?

Comment: like when we want to subtract $A_{1}$ from $A_{2}$ should not $A_{1}$ be inside $A_{2}$?

Comment: @Happy No, $A_2 \setminus A_1 = \{x \in A_2 \mid x \notin A_1\}$. This set could equal $A_2$ if $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$ already, e.g.

Comment: Sorry for my 4th comment from below ...I meant the reverse.

Comment: @Happy That's the same. The result is that the $B_i$ cover and are disjoint, which is what you want and each $B_i$ is a subset of $A_i$, so we have a refinement.

Comment: ohh, I see :) .... and your construction is clearly disjoint? correct?

Comment: @Happy yes, don’t you see why?

Comment: No I see this clearly :) we subtract from each one the previous one

Comment: @Happy for each $x \in X$, let $i(x) = \min \{i : x \in A_i\}$. Then only $B_{i(x)}$ can contain $x$. This shows the $B_i$ form a partition.

Comment: should not the $I$ capital be i small?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106509/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-happy).

Comment: and we need $B_{i}$ to form a partition so that they will be disjoint ... correct? so should I add your previous comment to the main answer?